# rake aborted! ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Email can't be blank, Password can't be blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am getting an error while doing

```
heroku run rake db:seed
```

> rake aborted!
>   ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Email can't be blank, Password can't be blank

I am using a rails composer app with Devise gem.
Any suggestions?!

Comment: check your model validations, as you are using devise email and password validation comes by default and show your `db:seed` code

Comment: can you post more information please? for example the model and the db:seed

Comment: user = CreateAdminService.new.call
    puts 'CREATED ADMIN USER: ' << user.email

Comment: check your `config/secrets.yml` file if `admin_email` and `admin_password` are present or not and before that check your database if admin user is present or not .

Comment: have you set your environment variables before deploying to Heroku. check [link](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-environment-variables.html) for Rails env variables

Comment: It works! Thank you. Sorry I did miss that